# How to do a first Click on button the Icon will change and the second click it will be go to the page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying do change my hamburger icon inside the button in nav when I first click it it will be a right icon by using transform,then after the second click it will show the nav menu. Is this possible in jquery? all can I do is when you hover the hamburger menu it will transform to a right icon, but I want is when it click it will change the icon then the second click will go to the link.

this is my code in hovering

```
button#responsive-menu-button:hover .responsive-menu-inner { 
background:rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;}
button#responsive-menu-button:hover .responsive-menu-inner:before { transform:rotate(45deg);}
button#responsive-menu-button:hover .responsive-menu-inner:after { transform:rotate(-45deg);}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle or share complete code ? . it would be easy to help you that way

Comment: @RashFlash the concept is something like this http://jsfiddle.net/7YATm/ when you click the button the hamburger icon will change to right icon using .responsive-menu-inner:before { transform:rotate(45deg);} .responsive-menu-inner:after{ transform:rotate(-45deg);} then the second click will show the nav menu and the icon is left, the Icon is already left so don't worry about that

Comment: you need to use javascript for that...use jquery...If you need that I can help you out

Comment: @Ashishsah yes I need to use a jquery in this

Comment: @JonnyDOe show us the code you've done so far..

Comment: hey your code on fiddle is working it is perfectly changing the background

Comment: @ShadowFiend okay just a minute

Comment: @Ashishsah it's not mine, but the concept is similar to that, but when I tried that, nothing change

Comment: Use the specific colour the background is changing perfectly

Comment: you need to use btn class in place of input why dont you share your code on js fiddle

Comment: @Ashishsah haha wait I'm transferring my code in fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0uc8o0nL/1/ like this but, it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [fiddle click here](https://jsfiddle.net/rehankhalid/crr6bmcw/), i update it with changes

Since you are changing ".before and .after" using jquery , best way is to make a class and add that.

**Css Changes**

```
.transformCL_1:before{
                transform:rotate(45deg);
            }
            .transformCL_1:after{
                transform:rotate(-45deg);
            }
```

**Javascript Function changes**

```
function viewSomething() {

                if (action == 1) {
                    $(".responsive-menu-inner").css("background", "rgba(0,0,0,0)");
                    $(".responsive-menu-inner").addClass('transformCL_1');

                    action = 2;
                } else {
                    $(".responsive-menu-inner").removeClass('transformCL_1');
                    /*will show the navigation menu and the icon will be left */
                    action = 1;
                }
            }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: something like this, but after the else will be a link to open the navigation, so I think I will  $("html").addClass('shownav');, is this right?

Comment: t's not working thou, it's still the same as before when I click the button it show the nav,

Comment: whats not working, explain in detail also wheres your "navigation"  code. update the fiddle with it

Comment: the navigation still show on first click, the navigation is just plugin installed by the previous dev., it should only show on 2nd click, because the 1st click is just change the icon and the second click will show the nav

Comment: i cannot help you this way. you need to show me some code of that plugin and how you are using it

Comment: i checked your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b1fhuqb6/ , which seems to be incomplete . how viewSomething() will run? you have not bind any event to button click. review your fiddle and put complete code in it

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's [one() method](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

For example, as follows:

```
$('button').one('click', doThis);

function doThis() {
    alert('doing this');
  $('button').one('click', doThat);
}

function doThat() {
    alert('doing that');
  $('button').one('click', doThis);
}
```

This snippet will initialise the button with a one-off function. Each time the button is clicked, it will be executing an alternating function. Here's your jsfiddle edited to showcase this:

https://jsfiddle.net/0uc8o0nL/4/

Comment: edit: stole RashFlash's js & css so my fiddle works  ;)

Comment: the concept is something like that